# Спасибо — в кавычках?

Tags: пунктуация

В словосочетании "сказать спасибо" нужно брать слово "спасибо" в кавычки?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> В словосочетании "сказать спасибо" нужно брать слово "спасибо" в
>   кавычки?

Не нужно.

См. ответы справочной службы Грамоты.ру:

[http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer/?s=Сказать%20спасибо](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer/?s=%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE)

Answer (score 1):

Словосочетание «сказать спасибо» — устойчивое, т. е. фразеологизм. Кавычки привнесли бы в него долю непредсказуемости эффекта.

Answer (score 0):

Сказать спасибо — это **устойчивое сочетание** со значением "поблагодарить", кавычки не нужны.

Однако "спасибо" может быть **дословным высказыванием** персонажа, и тогда используется упрощенное оформление прямой речи (прямая речь как дополнение), например:

**Она с нетерпением ждала ответа, но он только сказал "спасибо" и быстро вышел.**